# Generate random numeric vector with a given geometric mean

Tags: r

I have a number of elements n and a geometric mean mu. Using R, I want to generate a vector of n elements so that the realized vector has the exact geometric mean mu, with a way/parameter to control the dispersion of the numbers in the vector. I do not need the vector elements to be distributed in any particular way.

So far I have the following:

```
generateNoiseAroundReturns <- function(n, desired, sd){
  vec <- 0
  gm <- 0
  while (abs(gm - desired) > .00001){
    vec <- rnorm(n, mean = desired, sd = sd)
    gm <- geometricMean(vec)
  }
  return(vec)
}
```

which works, but I am wondering if I can do better/smarter/faster.

Thanks.

Comment: "a way/parameter to control the dispersion" seems vague. Generate a sample from normal distribution, and use variance as your "parameter". It would also be nice to see some code.

Comment: While I strongly recommend against forcing any moment of a sampled subset to come out "exact,"  the typical hack is to generate a sample set and then add one more value to make your parameter come out right.  However, this biases your sample  (and incidentally makes it much easier for Bletchley Park to decrypt your message :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work on the logarithmic scale:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(1e2, mean = log(5), sd = 2) #draw random sample
x <- (scale(x) * 2) + log(5) #to make it the exact mean
x <- exp(x) 

#geometric mean
prod(x)^(1/length(x))
#[1] 5
```

If you didn't need an "exact geometric mean", but rather an expected value, you could just use `rlnorm`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I needed the exact value and so rlnorm didn't work.